# Using Repeatable Field in Module Development + Media Field

Tags: development, module, joomla-3.3.x

Repeatable Fields seem to work OK in my Module (Joomla 3.3.6)

One of the repeatable fields is an image ref.

Tried to use 'media' field type here but I guess a modal inside a modal is a nono!

Is there a way around this ?

Comment: I don't believe there is a way around this so instead you will need to use a text field to manually enter the path of the media file. Perhaps have a separate parameter for the media type which will allow the user to upload their media.

Answer (score 1):

An update for those who may want to do this.

This is now working in Joomla 3.4.4. `media` type fields can now be used on repeatable form fields.